# VisualHG in VS 2017: commit all projects in a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visualhg

I have a C# solution with projects that are not all in folders under the *.sln directory. If I make a change in a file from such a lateral project and then try to commit the solution (as shown in picture below) these changes are not listed, but only those made in projects under the solution directory.

[image]

My experience is that the property to see differences from all projects, independently from their physical locations, is sometimes present. Sometimes not, however, and I do not see why. Where are the configuration data for VisualHG in VS 2017 telling it which projects to consider (when pushing 'commit solution')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to find these settings, either (to my experience, what you have described, happens really), but I can propose a workaround.

Namely, you can simply create a batch file (something like **my_batch_commit.bat**) where you will have a list of all local folders with your partial HG repositories, e.g

```
cd C:\MyProjects\Project_A
thg commit

cd C:\MyProjects\Project_B
thg commit

cd C:\MyProjects\Project_C
thg commit

REM ...
```

the folders are those where the corresponding **.hg** directories lie. **thg.exe** is the name of the Tortoise HG GUI (must be retrievable via PATH, but if Tortoise HG is correctly installed, this is fulfilled automatically).

If you now execute the batch file, you will be presented with a number of THG instances, one for each HG repository, so you can deal with them one after another.

Comment: Hi Francesca, my first test was somewhat superficial, in this form the script is not quite correct; it remains always in the same folder.
You need to change the script as follows:

thg commit --repository "C:\MyProjects\Project_A"

thg commit --repository "C:\MyProjects\Project_B"

thg commit --repository "C:\MyProjects\Project_C"

rem ...

Then it works correctly!

Sorry, in a comment I cannot format it, but I hope the idea is clear. And since this is not an answer to my question, it remains a comment.

Comment: @AlexKonnen You are correct, thanks for your addition!